# Basic CRUD to a SolrCloud instance via Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

I'm trying to do basic crud operations with Solr 5.3.1 (using SolrCloud) from my Rails app but am a bit confused on how to do so.

This is what I'm doing thus far:

1. Run `bin/solr start -e cloud`
2. This starts up `http://localhost:8983/solr/$my_collection/`
3. I see two shards from the admin ui: one on port 8983, one on 7574

From the rails console I then type

```
require 'net/http'
h = Net::HTTP.new 'localhost', 8983
data = Article.all.map {|a| {id: a.id, title: a.title, body: a.body, caption: a.caption}}
h.send_request 'POST', 'http://localhost:8983/solr/$my_collection/update', data, 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Then I get: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'keys' for "Content-Type: application/json":String`

I guess I need to add these keys somehow but not sure how.

This is also failing:

```
h = Net::HTTP.new 'localhost', 8983
h.send_request 'POST', 'http://localhost:8983/solr/$my_collection/update/json', "{'id': '1'}"

=> #<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

But working via simple curl commands:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/$my_collection/update/json' --data-binary "[{'id':94},{'id':93}]"
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":285}}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

**Edit:**
If you're curious, the `data`a variable would end up containing content like:

```
[
  {:id=>94, :title=>"Some Title", :body=> "Some body", :caption=> "Some caption"},
  {:id=>93, :title=>"Some Title", :body=> "Some body", :caption=> "Some caption"},
  {:id=>92, :title=>"Some Title", :body=> "Some body", :caption=> "Some caption"},
  {:id=>91, :title=>"Some Title", :body=> "Some body", :caption=> "Some caption"},
... and so on]
```

Comment: are you able to run the curl command for the same end points? Please try it out.

Comment: Yep, I've updated my original post with the curl command and its' output.

Comment: Now my guess is issue now down to the how to make REST call using ruby. Because solr API is working.

Comment: That is the million dollar question :)